# Switch divs off/on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once a div is offed can it be onned?

FIRST,

```
        $("#num-one").off();
        $("#num-two").off();
        $("#num-three").off();
```

THEN LATER ON,

```
        $("#num-one").on();
        $("#num-two").on();
        $("#num-three").on();
```

Because the divs are no longer responding to click events in spite of onning them - can they be onned once they are turned off?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind it again with parameters, "telling" them which event you want to bind and *what element* on which you want to bind the event.

```
$("#num-one").on('click', function(){
});
```

You an make a function and bind all events in it and call it when you want to bind.

```
function bindMyEvents()
{

    $("#num-one").on('click', function(){
    });

    $("#num-two").on('click', function(){
    });

    $("#num-three").on('click', function(){
    });

}

bindMyEvents(); // to bind the events with single call
```

or

Comment: So are you saying that this should be done, instead of the '$("#num-one").on();' technique?

Comment: No not necessarily you can use the syntax you had, I updated my code following your method.