# Turn Divs Off or On

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch divs off/on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107856/switch-divs-off-on)

Firstly, I realize that I have previously asked this question but I did not find a good response, so I am trying for a second time lucky!

I have these divs (*they work similarly to buttons*) that I would like to be able to switch on/off whenever I choose.

This was my attempt, but apparently once a div is switched off it can't be switched on again.

FIRST,

```
    $("#num-one").off();
    $("#num-two").off();
    $("#num-three").off();
```

THEN LATER ON,

```
    $("#num-one").on();
    $("#num-two").on();
    $("#num-three").on();
```

These are my functions:

```
$("#numOne").click(function(){
        doSomething();
    });

$("#numTwo").click(function(){
        doSomething();
    });

$("#numThree").click(function(){
        doSomething();
    });
```

These functions should work - but they should be able to stop working for sometime - disabled I guess - and re-enabled after sometime.
What is another way of achieving this?

Happy New Year!

Comment: Do not repeatedly post the same question.  If you don't get a good answer, follow [the advice in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: Ok - also note, Jim, I am not denying that it is similar to Switch divs off/on

Comment: m( 

Please, please... read http://api.jquery.com/on/, http://api.jquery.com/off/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/.

The methods `on` and `off` doesn't change the status of your buttons.
You should do this with the attributes `disabled` or `readonly`.

To bind some events to your buttons just write

    $( '#numOne' ).on( 'click', function() {
        doSomething();
    } );

This binds the `doSomething` function to them.

To enable/disable your buttons just try

    $( '#numOne' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );

to set the attribute `disabled` to the value `disabled`.

Comment: What about re-enabling it from disabled mode?

Answer (score 2):

Off() removes event handlers. If you want to re-add a handler, you must pass the handler to the on() method.

```
$("#num-one").on("click", doSomething);
$("#num-one").off();
$("#num-one").on("click", doSomething);

// a bit cleaner
var button = $("#num-one");

button.click(doSomething);
button.off();
button.click(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be wrote like this:

```
$("#num-one,#num-two,#num-three").off('click');

$("#num-one,#num-two,#num-three").on('click',doSomething);
```